# Send post request from one site to another

Tags: php, post

I was wondering, the firefox addon, (hackbar) has the option to send a post request to the given website.
Now the question is how do I send a post request in a php script to another site?
In this case the only post data will be:
*nick=bob*.
The site I want to send the post request to is:
*www.example.com*.
The php script will be hosted on *www.host.com*.
Thanks to anyone who can provide me with a straight forward php script to do this that can have such data easily replaceable with something else that I can suit to my own preference.

Comment: You could use curl for that.. Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want the end user of your website to send a POST request from their browser, or that you want your server-side code to send a POST request?

If the former, you can simply use that other site as the action in a `form`:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/somepage.php">
```

If the latter, you can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) to send a POST request.

**Edit:** Based on comments, it looks like what you're trying to achieve is to have a client-initiated `form` POST, but to initiate it from code without user interaction.  In this case you'd still have a `form` in the page.  Though it doesn't need to be displayed to the user.  Perhaps it could contain only hidden fields, for example.  Something like this:

```
<form id="someHiddenForm" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/somepage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="value1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="value2" />
</form>
```

Then in JavaScript you can invoke the submit action on that form:

```
document.getElementById('someHiddenForm').submit();
```

Just be careful with something like this.  Automatically posting a form to another site without user interaction is very close to a couple of different attempts at security exploits.  And at the very least may be an undesirable action for some users.  Just be aware of that.

Comment: Yes, i meant, that if www.example.com/codetosendpostrequest.php is visited, the post request is automatically sent without forms. How can i do that? I'm not really good at php.

Comment: @user2536979: That doesn't answer if the request is intended to be sent from the client or from the server.  The two are *very* different options.  Also, your example is now somewhat confusing.  Your page is on `www.mysite.com` and the target is on `www.example.com`.  But now you're saying that the user is visiting `www.example.com`, so what is your site actually doing in this scenario?  Or, when you say "automatically sent without forms" do you mean that it should be an AJAX request from the user's web browser?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. When www.example.com is visited i want www.host.com/codetosendpostrequestoexample.com.php to be launched and automatically send the post request to www.example.com through the user's browser.

Comment: @user2536979: You would still essentially be using a `form` element.  However, you don't have to display that form to the user (it can contain only hidden fields, for example) and you can submit it via JavaScript.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes i'll use javascript to do it.

Comment: No, i need some php code and call the .php script through javascript without a redirect.

Comment: @user2536979: It continues to be very unclear what you're trying to do, then.  For one thing, if the request has to be submitted from the user's web browser then it doesn't happen with PHP code.  PHP runs server-side, not in the browser.  If you want the submit to happen without reloading the page then you can do it with AJAX.  jQuery makes this pretty easy: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an outside page for your php script I think you should use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for that. It will give you whatever that page gives you.

But if you just need some data from that site you could use ajax to do it client side too.